# Unpickle element that was pickled with SQLAlchemy "by hand"

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pickle

I have an application that pickles some python Elements into a Database.
The SQLAlchemyCode looks like this:

```
class DatabaseTable(base):
    __tablename__ = 'TableName'
    id = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    pickeled_element_column = Column(sqlalchemy.types.PickleType, nullable=False)
```

No i can put elements into my Database with:

```
db_object = DatabaseTable()
db_object.pickeled_element_column = object_to_pickle
session.add(db_object)
session.commit()
```

That works so far.

The application mentioned above is allready in a productive use. What I want to do now is to copy some of those database elements into my jupyter notebook to play around and test some things.

My thought was to copy my object by hand from database into a python string within jupyter. The pickle string from my database looks like:

```
pickle_string = 0x800495FF020000000...5622E
```

When i no try to unpickle that string i get an unpickling stack underflow Error:

```
pickle.loads(pickle_string.encode())

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-508-58d250332c2d> in <module>()
      1 pickeled_string = "0x800495FF020000..E"
      2 
----> 3 pickle.loads(pickeled_string.encode())

UnpicklingError: unpickling stack underflow
```

So finally here is my question.
How to copy an element pickled into a database by SQLAlchemy and unpickle it somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `0x800495FF020000..E` is a [T-SQL binary constant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#binary-constants), or in other words the way SQL Server displays binary data. Python's [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) on the other hand expects [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) – not a string containing the representation of a T-SQL binary constant. You'll have to convert the representation before you can unpickle your object:

```
# I'll assume you actually have the full binary string without the `..` truncation
binary_constant = "0x800495FF020000..E"
pickled_data = bytes.fromhex(binary_constant[2:])
obj = pickle.loads(pickled_data)
```

In case you're still using Python 2 (you should migrate to 3), which you would seem to be given that `pickle.loads()` accepts a string value, you will have to use a bit different method:

```
import binascii

binary_constant = "0x800495FF020000..E"
pickled_data = binascii.unhexlify(binary_constant[2:])
obj = pickle.loads(pickled_data)
```

Comment: that was exactly what i was looking for, thanks a lot!